# XSLT transformation changing namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-2.0, xml-signature

I have the following XML (Much of the data is dummy)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<msg xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m1"  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
<header>
    <nodeA>aaaaaaaaaaa</nodeA>
    <nodeB>bbbbbbbb</nodeB>
</header>
<payload>
    <calcnode   xmlns="http://someaddress/nodeC"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
        <somefield>field</somefield>
    </calcnode>
    <ds:Signature>
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="#kjbn34jkb5j-3k45j-k3jb534jkb534k5">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>+se0dfgft9gh8hjuji7ji65ko4ko3ko2</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>sekfrhsdkjfhsdkjfhksd</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>sdjkfhsdkfhskdf</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</payload>
</msg>
```

And all I want to do is change the name of the `msg` element (to `newmsg`) and the default namespace to `http://someaddress.com/m2`. Everything else should be kept as is. the closest I have been able to get is this xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msg="http://someaddress.com/m1" >

<!-- the identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace namespace of elements in old namespace -->
<xsl:template match="msg:msg">
  <xsl:element name="newmsg" namespace="http://someaddress.com/m2">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using xalan for testing and this is the output xml I get when running the above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <newmsg xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<header xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <nodeA>aaaaaaaaaaa</nodeA>
    <nodeB>bbbbbbbb</nodeB>
</header>
<payload xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <calcnode xmlns="http://someaddress/nodeC" xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
        <somefield>field</somefield>
    </calcnode>
    <ds:Signature>
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="#kjbn34jkb5j-3k45j-k3jb534jkb534k5">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>+se0dfgft9gh8hjuji7ji65ko4ko3ko2</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>sekfrhsdkjfhsdkjfhksd</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>sdjkfhsdkfhskdf</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</payload>
</newmsg>
```

There are 2 main problems with this:

1. The `ds` namespace simply disappears from the output and I don't know why.
2. The second issue is that it drops the `xsi` namespace from the `calcnode` and given that the `calcnode` is the node used to calculate (and verify) the signature (Which comes below that section) such change would make verification of the signature impossible to my understanding.

I have tried several different iterations of the xslt without much results. Could anybody shed some light in the situation?

Comment: Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor, but your stylesheet is XSLT 2.0. Use Saxon 9.4 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:oldDef="http://someaddress.com/m1" exclude-result-prefixes="oldDef">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]|@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http://someaddress.com/m1']">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://someaddress.com/m2">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="oldDef:msg[true()]">
  <newmsg xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m2">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name()]|@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </newmsg>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<msg xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m1"  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
<header>
    <nodeA>aaaaaaaaaaa</nodeA>
    <nodeB>bbbbbbbb</nodeB>
</header>
<payload>
    <calcnode   xmlns="http://someaddress/nodeC"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
        <somefield>field</somefield>
    </calcnode>
    <ds:Signature>
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="#kjbn34jkb5j-3k45j-k3jb534jkb534k5">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>+se0dfgft9gh8hjuji7ji65ko4ko3ko2</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>sekfrhsdkjfhsdkjfhksd</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>sdjkfhsdkfhskdf</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</payload>
</msg>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<newmsg xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
   <header>
      <nodeA>aaaaaaaaaaa</nodeA>
      <nodeB>bbbbbbbb</nodeB>
   </header>
   <payload>
      <calcnode xmlns="http://someaddress/nodeC" xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
         <somefield>field</somefield>
      </calcnode>
      <ds:Signature>
         <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="#kjbn34jkb5j-3k45j-k3jb534jkb534k5">
               <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
               <DigestValue>+se0dfgft9gh8hjuji7ji65ko4ko3ko2</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
         </SignedInfo>
         <SignatureValue>sekfrhsdkjfhsdkjfhksd</SignatureValue>
         <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
               <X509Certificate>sdjkfhsdkfhskdf</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
         </KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
   </payload>
</newmsg>
```

Comment: Thanks. May I point out that the wanted result is not to actually change anything in the xml except the mentioned parts which is not the case here (though still a valid xml) but it seems that may be impossible so I'll see if it is somehow possible to use that.

Comment: @NooK, Correct, this is a lexical difference only, and cannot be controlled by the serialization of the XSLT results.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the ds namespace in the `<xsl:stylesheet` element of your XSLT, though the ds namespace isn't lost, it's just distributed to all the child elements of newmsg. Similarly, the xsi namespace is applied to the root element (newmsg) and therefore will apply to the calcnode as well.

The output appears to be valid, even though some of the namespace declarations have moved.

I've written an article with some information about controlling namespaces that may provide some insight: [Transforming XHTML using XSLT identity templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-tipxsltidentitytpl/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> And all I want to do is change the name of the msg element (to newmsg) and the default namespace to http://someaddress.com/m2. Everything else should be kept as is.

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msg="http://someaddress.com/m1">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Process all elements (except 'msg') in the 'msg' namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="msg:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://someaddress.com/m2">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Change 'msg' element into 'newmsg' -->
  <xsl:template match="msg:msg">
    <xsl:element name="newmsg" namespace="http://someaddress.com/m2" >
      <!-- Keep "ds" declaration on the root element -->
      <xsl:namespace name="ds" select="'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the stylesheet is applied to the XML source, it outputs (using Saxon 9.4):

```
<newmsg xmlns="http://someaddress.com/m2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
  <header>
    <nodeA>aaaaaaaaaaa</nodeA>
    <nodeB>bbbbbbbb</nodeB>
  </header>
  <payload>
    <calcnode xmlns="http://someaddress/nodeC" xsi:schemaLocation="http://someaddress/somexsd.xsd">
      <somefield>field</somefield>
    </calcnode>
    <ds:Signature>
      <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <Reference URI="#kjbn34jkb5j-3k45j-k3jb534jkb534k5">
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <DigestValue>+se0dfgft9gh8hjuji7ji65ko4ko3ko2</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>sekfrhsdkjfhsdkjfhksd</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
        <X509Data>
          <X509Certificate>sdjkfhsdkfhskdf</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
  </payload>
</newmsg>
```

This is not **exactly** what you want, but it's close. There is still no `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` declaration on the `calcnode` element, because `xsi` is already declared on the root element. If this is a problem for the signature processing, I'm not sure how to address that.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be close indeed though probably the closest possible under the circumstances. I did get a slightly different result with more namespaces than shown above however that may be due to slightly different data.